# Laravel Envoy and bash prompt

Tags: bash, laravel, laravel-envoy

I'm using Envoy to provision a remote server. Provisioning is done by pulling the bash script from a private repo and then execute it.

The bash script ask some confirmation like yes/no (using bash "read -p"): it works as expected when i'm connected to the remote server... the script wait for user input.

Instead Envoy seems to ignore any prompt. Is it an expected behavior?

Any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is expected. There's nothing for `read` to read from so it doesn't.

You have a few options.

1. Rewrite your script to use a config file when there's no terminal to prompt from.

   Use something like `[ -t 0 ]` to test if the standard input is a terminal and load a configuration file with defaults. The simplest way to do that is just have a file that contains appropriate variable assignments and just source it `. defaults.sh` or whatever. You don't even need the `-t` test if you source the defaults first since then anything the user inputs will over-ride the default value.
2. Rewrite your script to have sane defaults.
3. Rewrite whatever runs the script to provide your script input via pipeline/file via redirection (e.g. `printf 'answer 1\nanswer 2\n' | ./script.sh` or `./script.sh <answerfile`).

Comment: Thanks for explanation Etan. Could you please provide an example of the first option?